# Graphing something on matlab

Tags: matlab, coordinates, calculus, polar-coordinates

So im trying to draw on Matlab and this is what I have so far from my source code:

```
phi=linspace(0,pi,100);
theta=linspace(0,pi,100);
r=phi.^2+theta.^2;

x=r.*sin(phi).*cos(theta);
y=r.*sin(phi).*sin(theta);
z=r.*cos(phi);
plot3(x,y,z,'*')
```

However this only gives me one slice, I want multiple slices. How do I go about doing this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- In your code as it stands, `theta` and `phi` are *vectors*. Each value of `phi` is associated with a value of `theta`. That gives a line, not a surface. To generate a surface you need to generate a grid with all the combinations of `theta`, `phi` values in the form of *matrices*. This can be done with [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html).
- The equations for the torus seem to be wrong. I'm taking them from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus).
- `theta`, `phi` should vary from `0` to `2*pi` (not from `0` to `pi`).

Code:

```
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
[pp, tt] = ndgrid(phi,theta);
R = 1;
r = 1;
x = (R+r.*cos(tt)).*cos(pp);
y = (R+r.*cos(tt)).*sin(pp);;
z = r.*sin(tt);
plot3(x,y,z,'*')
```

Figure:

[image]

Comment: That is totally psychedelic! https://frontpsych.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/psychedelic.jpeg

Comment: @rayryeng Dizzying! :-)

Comment: WOW you are awesome. Thank you so muchh:)